100ms delay between pointermove events in Android webviews?
I noticed that gesture animations in Android webviews felt laggy, so after some debugging, I found the root cause: pointermove events have a ~100ms delay between them whereas it should be a ~17ms delay.
In Android Chrome, when performing a gesture, the timeline looks something like:
0ms: pointerdown
3ms: pointermove
10ms: pointermove
27ms: pointermove
44ms: pointermove


In Android webviews, it's something like:
0ms: pointerdown
3ms: pointermove
100ms: pointermove
117ms: pointermove
134ms: pointermove


In each screenshot, I hovered over the first pointermove, then you can see each subsequent pointermove as yellow blocks.
Is this a known webview issue? Is there a way to control the frequency of pointermove? It doesn't look like the thread is busy, so I have no idea why the second pointermove is always delayed by ~100ms.

Part of the problem is probably IPC.  The WebView UI element is in the client application.  The WebView interpreter is in the WebView process.  Everything needs to be sent via IPC between one and the other.  This breakdown allows Android to update WebView with security fixes without you needing to update your app, but has some costs as well.  Although I'd point out in your data if you ignore a single 100ms delay the numbers look similar.  So I'd be looking to see if that's repeatable, and if your host app is using its main thread, which would delay touch processing

It appears that you have encountered a delay in the frequency of pointermove events in Android WebViews, which is not present in Android Chrome. This issue might be related to the differences in event handling between the two environments.the frequency of pointermove events is not something that can be directly controlled from within your web application. It is determined by the underlying browser engine and the operating system.
